# Rails ActiveRecord_Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently developing a somewhat 'big' project. In this project I have many models, views, and controllers from which I have to mention the following:
Group.rb:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, through: :grouprel
    has_many :grouprel, dependent: :destroy
    validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 25},
                              uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :description, presence: true , length: {maximum: 140}
end
```

Grouprel.rb

```
class Grouprel < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :group
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :group_id, presence: true
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
.....
  has_many :groups, through: :grouprel, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :grouprel, dependent: :destroy
.....
```

StaticPageController:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if logged_in?
      @tweet = current_user.tweets.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
      @groupi = Grouprel.where(user_id: current_user.id).pluck(:group_id)
      @groupies = Group.where(id: @groupi).paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end
.....

end
```

Home.html.erb:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
.......
      <section class="user_info">
        <%= render 'shared/group_participation' %>
      </section>
    </aside>
 .............
```

_group_participation.html.erb

```
<h5> Your groups: </h5>
<% if @groupies %>
<ol class="tweets">
    <%= content_tag_for(:li, @groupies) do %>
      <%= link_to @groupies.name, group_path(@groupies) %>
    <% end %>
</ol>
 <%= will_paginate @groupies %>
<% end %>
```

here I want to display every single group that a user is part of. The error I get when trying to get the @groupies in the StaticPagesController is `%23<Group::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f86b00f6ed0>` . I checked in my rails console , and it should return something.

What my limited knowledge about rails and ruby can tell is that this is a problem because the StaticPageController can't see the Grouprel.rb table. I tried to include controllers in herlpers. I even tried to define a method that returns 'groupies' in the application controller and then use that in the StaticPagesController. Could I get a hint of why I get that error returned ?

If my post has to contain any more specifications please do tell I will post them the second I see the request

Comment: Have you tried to get groups by user.groups ?

Comment: I did try , but to make that work I am missing something at every single exercise I try to do, so I gave up on that until I see my teacher again to ask him :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not iterating over the `groupies` collection and are calling the `name` method on the collection itself. `content_tag_for` *can* iterate over the collection for you but you need to use the value it yields to the block:

```
<%= content_tag_for(:li, @groupies) do |group| %>
  <%= link_to group.name, group_path(group) %>
<% end %>
```